# What is a good plastic to use for lite milling?

Tags: tools, materials

I want to do some lite milling with a drill press and XY vice using plastic. I am looking for a cheap easy to machine plastic. I have dealt with [these guys](https://www.onlinemetals.com/plasticguide.cfm) for aluminum, but not plastics. I don't know much about the different types of plastics yet. I see a white plastic in many projects that is often milled, but I can't find the name of it.

Comment: Delrin or nylon are easily machinable.

Comment: Delrin is the classic.  Depending on your application, Machinable Wax may be useful as well.